# Why is inflation described by a scalar field?

Tags: cosmology, field-theory, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation

Textbooks on cosmology describe the phenomenon of cosmic inflation in terms of the existence of a scalar field (or many scalar fields, as the answer and comments pointed out), called inflaton. Such as choice without motivation seems ad hoc. Is there a reason why inflaton should be a scalar field (instead of a fermionic or vector field) apart from making the theory simple?

Comment: Much about inflation is ad hoc ...

Comment: This might have something to do with the potential. I.e. in  slow roll  inflation, you want to have a potential of a  certain shape, being flat at the start, so it 'rolls slowly' and running into a potential minimum to oscillate and start the reheating phase, producing standard model particles. It might be that you cannot achieve this with fermions so easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are hundreds of inflationary models, and some of them indeed use vector fields (I'm sure you can come up with spinor models as well). But then you can ask yourself - why describe inflation with "100" scalar fields, when you can just as well describe it with only one? Of course you should keep in mind those other possibilities, but lean towards the simplest ones.

Good textbooks make it clear that inflation is a paradigm, not a theory, and focus on general aspects of inflation that are common to all possible models.

Comment: Just a note to OP: People do work on multiple field inflation too https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0702187

Comment: My question was not _"Why one or many scalar fields?"_ but _"Why scalar fields? Why are scalars fields preferred? Just for simplicity?"_ @Avantgarde

Comment: @SRS I know. My comment was merely a side note to the answer.